# Unknown error on booting my linux system

Tags: ubuntu, boot, hard-disk, disk

On booting my linux system recently started to show a series of errors and after that it boot perfectly.
can anyone tell whats causing these errors and how can i correct it.?
[image: error message on bot]

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to U&L , What is your Linux distro ?

Comment: i am using ubuntu 16.10

Answer (score 0):

Those are Sata port errors. It could be a busted port or cable, but more likely it is a damaged hard disk.

If it boots, or you can boot with another drive, run:

```
fsck /dev/sdX
```

(replace sdX with the proper drive name)

Comment: sudo fsck /dev/sdX

Comment: but i cant run fsck on mounted volumes ryt.

Comment: right now my disk have a single partition with contains all the os files. so i cant unmount it and run fsck